# What can a ruby symbol (syntax) contain?

Tags: ruby, symbols

I want to create regular expression to match ruby symbols, but I need to know what the exact syntax for a symbol is.

Until now I am aware of the following:

```
:'string'
:"string"
:__underline
:method
:exclamation!
:question?
:@instance
:$global
```

Comment: Why you want to match symbols with regexp?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but if you can use `:'any string'`, then surely anything that's valid in a string is valid in a symbol.

Comment: I'm doing it for a templating engine.

Comment: :D, :-) and :-/ are also symbols.

Comment: @VitaliiElenhaupt only the first one is valid Ruby.

Comment: @PatrickOscity Of course you need to quote 2nd and 3rd like `:"-)"`, `:"-/"`. But is this case they do not like so good. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: Sorry I was too pedantic :-) No offense!

Comment: @VitaliiElenhaupt fun fact: because Ruby will treat almost all unicode characters as valid parts of symbols, `:` actually is a valid symbol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are talking about.

If you are talking about what a `Symbol` can contain, the answer is: anything and everything, including newlines, arbitrary whitespace, control characters, arbitrarily weird and obscure Unicode characters, and everything else.

If you are talking about the various ways of writing `Symbol` literals, here's my best understanding:

- bare `:` literal: any valid Ruby identifier (e.g. `:foo`, `:Foo`, `:@foo`, `:@@foo`, `:$foo`, `:$:`, …)
- single-quoted `:` literal: everything that's valid in a single-quoted `String` literal, including escape sequences such as `:'\''` and `:'\\'`
- double-quoted `:` literal: everything that's valid in a double-quoted `String` literal, including escape sequences such as `:"\""`, `:"\\"`, and `:"\n"`, as well as string interpolation, which allows you to inject the results of arbitrary Ruby code into the `Symbol`, e.g. `:"#{if rand < 0.5 then RUBY_VERSION else ENV['HOME'] end}"`
- single-quoted `Array` of `Symbol`s literal: everything that's valid in a single-quoted `Array` of `String`s literal, e.g. `%i|foo bar baz|` (equivalent to `[:foo, :bar, :baz]`), `%i(foo\ bar baz)` (equivalent to `[:'foo bar', :baz]`), `%i:foo bar:` (equivalent to `[:foo, :bar]`)
- double-quoted `Array` of `Symbol`s literal: everything that's valid in a double-quoted `Array` of `String`s literal, e.g. `%I|foo #{bar} baz|`, etc.
- `Symbol` hash keys in the `key: value` syntax: every valid Ruby label, e.g. `{foo: 42}`
- `Symbol` hash keys in the quoted `'key': value` syntax: every valid Ruby `String` literal, including escape sequences and interpolation, e.g. `{"foo\n#{bar}": 42}`

There are of course a lot of other expressions that evaluate to `Symbol`s:

- method definition expressions: `def foo;end # => :foo`
- `String#to_sym` (alias `String#intern`): `'foo bar'.to_sym # => :'foo bar'`
- really, *any* method that may `return` a `Symbol`

Comment: Very thorough explanation. Thank you very much! I have accepted your answer as the correct one since I can see you've put a lot of work into it and you've answered my question best.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/cse305/RubyBNF.pdf enumerates the context-free grammar productions that define Ruby's syntax. CFGs are inherently more powerful than REs, so you might want to consider a different tool for this job--but you can certainly look at this document and try to construct a regexp that matches all cases.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. I'm creating my own parser for a templating system, so I can now integrate embedded ruby properly.