# Confused about the million ways to reach inside Ruby Hash with the symbol sign

Tags: ruby, hash

I am drowning in the million ways to access Hash.

```
condition1 = {
    "e" =>1
}

condition2 = {
    "e":1
}

condition3 = {
    :"e" =>3
}


condition4 = {
    e:4
}


condition5 = {  # 100% sure not working because of syntax error
    e=>5
}

condition6 = {  # 100% sure not working because of syntax error
    :e:6
}  

condition7 = {
    :e=>7
}

puts condition1["e"]
puts condition2["e"]
puts condition3[:e]
puts condition4[:e]
puts condition7[:e]
```

**Output**:

```
1
                                     (nothing)
3
4
7
```

**First question: For the first 2 puts statement,** why is it working for the first one but not the second one?  In both hashes, I am using Strings as keys. Is it because I used "=>" in the first Hash and thus the string is actually being read as Symbols? So it is actually being processed like :"e" =>1?

**Second question: That leads to my second question about the third condition**, I was told that if I used Symbol sign before a quote, what happens in the background is that the quote will be ignored. That's why I was able to access it through simply :e without the quotes. Is that true? However if that's true,  then the first question becomes more confusing. If in the first condition, "e"=>1 was evaluated as :"e" =>1, then shouldn't the quotes be ignored? Thus eventually it's read as :e =>1. Then how come I was able to access it with only the quotes?

**Third question: So how do I access the second condition?** I know it's not recommended to use strings as key values. However what if in a certain case I have already created it with strings, how do I access it? I have tried accessing it through a variable name but it's still not outputing anything.

Thank you so much for reading this. I know it's definitely not worth it to care too much about these details. But I ran into it today and can't really move on without figuring out what the HECK is going on !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Rule of thumb

> If there's a colon (`:`) it's a Symbol. If there's a hashrocket (`=>`), it's whatever is to the left of the hashrocket (which can be anything).

### Declaring keys in a Hash literal

When we say "Hash literal" we mean code that declares a Hash with curly braces (`{ foo: 1 }`) or as method arguments (`bar(baz: 2)`).

There are two ways to declare a key in a Hash literal.

#### Keys with hashrockets (`=>`)

The first way to declare a key is with the hashrocket (`=>`). When you use the hashrocket, the key is whatever value is to the left of it, and you can put *any* kind of object (or expression) to the left of it:

```
hashrocket_hash = {
  "I am a String" => 1,
  :I_am_a_Symbol => 2,
  :"I am also a Symbol" => 4,
  /I am a Regexp!/ => 5,
  Kernel => 6,
  if true then "I am also a String" end => 7,
  nil => 8
}

p hashrocket_hash.keys
# => [ "I am a String",
#      :I_am_a_Symbol,
#      :"I am also a Symbol",
#      /I am a Regexp!/,
#      Kernel,
#      "I am also a String",
#      nil
#    ]

p hashrocket_keys.map(&:class)
# => [ String,
#      Symbol,
#      Symbol,
#      Regexp,
#      Module,
#      String,
#      NilClass
#    ]
```

#### Keys with colons (`:`)

The other way to declare a key is with a colon (`:`). When you use a colon the resulting key is *always* a Symbol. The usual Symbol rules apply (read the very thorough answer here: [What can a ruby symbol (syntax) contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526761/what-can-a-ruby-symbol-syntax-contain)) except the colon goes at the end instead of the beginning:

```
colon_hash = {
  I_am_a_Symbol: 9,
  "I am also a Symbol": 10
}

p colon_hash.keys
# => [ :I_am_a_Symbol,
#      :"I am also a Symbol" ]

p colon_hash.keys.map(&:class)
# => [ Symbol,
#      Symbol ]
```

### Accessing a Hash value

There are no special rules for accessing a Hash value. If you want to access a value whose key is a Symbol, you must use a Symbol. If you want to access a value whose key is a String, you must use a String. If the key is something else, you must use that thing.

In the below examples, pay close attention to which keys are followed by colons and which are followed by hashrockets:

```
hsh1 = { foo: 1 }
p hsh1[:foo]   # => 1
p hsh1[:"foo"] # => 1
p hsh1["foo"]  # => nil

hsh2 = { "bar": 2 }
p hsh2[:bar]   # => 2
p hsh2[:"bar"] # => 2
p hsh2["bar"]  # => nil

hsh3 = {
  Kernel: 3,
  Kernel => 4
}
p hsh3[:Kernel]  # => 3
p hsh3[Kernel]   # => 4
p hsh3["Kernel"] # => nil
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the "rule of thumb" pretty much answered all my questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion is caused by 2 causes, first, the syntax of symbol literal, and the second, the syntax of hash literal.

## The symbol literals

The most basic form of a symbol is `:hello_world`.

However, in order to allow symbol literals contain special characters, ruby introduces this syntax: `:'hello-world'` or `:"hello-world"`.

## The hash literals

Unlike JSON objects in javascript which only allows strings to be the keys, ruby allows anything to serve as a hash key, so the basic form of a hash is

```
{
  key1 => value1,
  key2 => value2,
  ...
}
```

Notice that `key1`, `key2` and `value1`, `value2` are just placeholders. You can replace them with anything, which can be:

- literals
- variables
- constants (including classes and modules)
- method calls

So when using symbol literals as keys and `Fixnum` literals as values, the basic form is

```
{:e => 1}
```

or

```
{:"e" => 1}
```

or

```
{:'e' => 1}
```

Because symbol literals are often used as hash keys (because they are immutable), Ruby introduced a shorthand version of this specific case: moving the `:` to the tail of the key, and omit the `=>`.

```
{e: 1}
```

or

```
{'e': 1}
```

or

```
{"e": 1}
```

Note that there must not be any spaces between `e` and `:`, otherwise there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that there's a huge difference in Ruby between String and Symbol, and that they are in no way equivalent. You can convert, and sometimes there's methods that take either one indifferently, so the line can be blurred, but this is the exception and not the rule.

As such `"e"` and `:e` are not equivalent, especially when it comes to a plain hash.

Here's your examples evaluated by Ruby in `irb`:

```
{ "e" => 1 } # Classic notation with String key
# => {"e"=> 1}

{ "e": 1 } # New notation with symbol
# => {:e=>1}

{ :"e" =>3 } # Classic notation with alternate Symbol representation
# => {:e=>3}

{ e: 4 } # New notation with Symbol key
# => {:e=>4}

{ e => 5 } # Uses variable e as key, but no such variable exists

{ :e:6 } # Invalid notation, not supported by Ruby syntax.

{ :e=>7 } # Classic notation with Symbol key
# => {:e=>7}
```

Using a tool like `irb` is important when learning, it will immediately show you how any given notation is interpreted.

`:e` and `:"e"` are equivalent, as is `"e".to_sym`. Likewise `:e.to_s` and `"e"` are equivalent, that's basically the reverse: `:e.to_s.to_sym` is also `:e`, going full circle.

To access symbol keys, `:e`, string `"e"`. You can even have a Hash with both!

```
{ :e => 'symbol', 'e' => 'string' }
```

So keep that in mind. Symbol is great for things you have control over that are repeated frequently. String is better when you're not sure what you're dealing with or the keys are unpredictable, like UUID values or dates and times.

Don't forget a Hash can store just about anything, so you can even do this:

```
class E
end

e = E.new

{ E => 'Class', e => 'Instance' }
```

Now you've got both a class and an instance in your Hash.