# Ruby Syntax of '=>'

Tags: ruby, syntax

The use of `=>` in ruby with hashes seems straightforward:

```
a = {key1: => value1, key2: => value2}
b = {"key1" => value1, "key2" => value2}
```

Ruby makes quite a little bit of use of syntactic sugar. Here's an example code block

```
begin
   [some code]
rescue Exception => e
   [some error handling code]
end
```

What exactly is going on in the rescue line, particularly between `Exception` and the variable `e` with the `=>` in between? `rescue` is a reserved keyword, `e` is clearly a variable. The rest? What is the function of `=>` in this case?

**Update**
Everyone appears to be missing the point. I know "rescue Exception => e" has nothing to do with hashes. I want to know syntactically what is going on in that line.

The word "rescue" is a keyword reserved word and is part of the ruby language. I'm pretty sure "e" is a variable, and could just as functionally be "a", "b", or "c". What are "Exception" and "=>"? Is there another way to write this expression to make it more intelligible to a guy like me who cut his programming teeth on languages with rigid syntax and no syntactic sugar?

Comment: `{ key1: "cat" }`  is shorthand for `{ :key1 => "cat" }`, but `{ key1: => "cat" }` is incorrect syntax. Sometimes you will see `{ "key1": "cat" }`. That's the same as `{ key1: "cat" }`, but symbols containing spaces must be quoted, so the shorthand form of `{:"key 1" => "cat}` is `{ "key 1": "cat" }` (quotes required).

Comment: So I think everyone is missing the gist of my question. I care little about the nuances of rescue and only put that code out there because it has an example of the syntactical construct I'm wishing to understand fully. See my update above for additional detail.

Comment: My earlier comment is correct, but incomplete, as symbols that must be quoted are by no means limited to those containing spaces. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526761/what-can-a-ruby-symbol-syntax-contain).

Answer (score 4):

By default, `rescue` only rescues  [`RuntimeError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html), which is also a default class for `raise` without an explicit exception class declaration:

```
begin
  raise "foo"
rescue
  puts "rescued"
end
```

If there is a need to get an access to the exception instance, one might use the following syntax:

```
begin
  raise "foo"
rescue => e
  puts "rescued #{e.message}"
end
```

One also might rescue different exceptions in different clauses:

```
class Error1 < RuntimeError; end
class Error2 < RuntimeError; end

begin
  [some code]
rescue Error1 => e
  puts "rescued an instance of Error1: #{e.message}"
rescue Error2 => e
  puts "rescued an instance of Error2: #{e.message}"
rescue => e # standard RuntimeError
  puts "rescued a generic error: #{e.message}"
end
```

That said, this syntax has nothing to do with hashes and it’s used to distinguish between different exception classes in many `rescue` blocks.

In your example, there is an `Exception` (which is not a successor of `RuntimeError` and is not rescued by default) rescued. While it’s considered to be a bad practice (for the reasons margins here are too tiny to describe,) sometimes it’s still of some use.

Comment: http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/28/why-you-should-never-rescue-exception-in-ruby/ for more details on `rescue Exception`