# Ruby Syntax of '=>' (hashrocket)

Tags: ruby, syntax

I tried this [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751986/ruby-syntax-of) and everyone got off on rescue block syntax. **Please don't go there**. Given the following working code:

```
begin
  (1..1000).each do |i|
    puts i
    sleep 1
  end
rescue Exception => e
   puts "\nCaught exception..."
   puts "Exception class: #{e.class}"
end
```

Pressing CTRL+C while it is running prints out "Caught exception...", as expected. What exactly is going on **syntax wise** in the rescue line, particularly between `Exception` and the variable `e` with the `=>` in between?

The word "rescue" is a keyword... part of the ruby language. "e" is a variable, and could just as functionally be "a", "b", or "c". The following code works just as well.

```
begin
  (1..1000).each do |i|
    puts i
    sleep 1
  end
rescue Exception => b
   puts "\nCaught exception..."
   puts "Exception class: #{b.class}"
end
```

What are "Exception" and "=>"? Is there another way to write this expression to make it more intelligible from a syntactical point of view? I don't think we're dealing with a hash here because the following code compiles but throws an error as soon as CTRL+C is pressed (undefined local variable or method `e').

```
begin
  (1..1000).each do |i|
    puts i
    sleep 1
  end
rescue { Exception => b }
   puts "\nCaught exception..."
   puts "Exception class: #{b.class}"
end
```

Can someone explain what is going on? and specifically what language element '=>' (hashrocket) is in this specific example since it seems to have nothing to do with hashes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sorry to inform you that this is just one-off syntax that doesn't really have any relation to other Ruby syntax.

Given the expression:

```
begin
  # ...
rescue FooError, BarError => ex
  # ...
end
```

- **`FooError, BarError`** is the list of exception classes (usually subclasses of [`StandardError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/StandardError.html)) that will be rescued. This behaves just like an argument list, so you can (if you want) do stuff like this:

  ```
  my_exception_classes = [ FooError, BarError ]

  begin
    # ...
  rescue *my_exception_classes => ex
    # ...
   end
  ```

  It's worth noting that you shouldn't, generally, use `Exception` here because it will rescue *all* exceptions, including things like `SignalException::Interrupt` and `NoMemoryError`, which [usually isn't what you want](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-exception-vs-standarderror-whats-the-difference/).
- **`=>`** is just syntax, and arguably not the best choice of syntax for the reason that it leads to questions like your own.
- **`ex`** is the name of a local variable into which the exception object will be put.

### Digging deeper

If you're into reading parser grammars, it's always fun looking at Ruby's YACC grammar in [`parse.y`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/84d0667ea8211fad830e744ab9cacd3f1770395d/parse.y). It's not especially easy to read, but we can see the grammar for a `rescue` expression, called [`opt_rescue`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/84d0667ea8211fad830e744ab9cacd3f1770395d/parse.y#L5050-L5052) in the grammar, here:

```
opt_rescue  : k_rescue exc_list exc_var then
              compstmt
              opt_rescue
```

`k_rescue` is of course the keyword `rescue`. `exc_list` is the list of exception classes which, like I said, is just like an argument list:

```
exc_list    : arg_value
```

`exc_var` is the part where the variable to put the exception in is designated:

```
exc_var     : tASSOC lhs
```

And here, `tASSOC` is of course our friend the hashrocket (`=>`), and `lhs`, i.e. “left-hand side,” is an expression you'd find to the left of an assignment expression (like, say, the name of a variable).

`compstmt` is basically “any valid Ruby code,” and then there’s `opt_rescue` again, since you can (optionally) have many `rescues` in a `begin` or `def` block.

As you can see, the only thing this syntax has in common with a Hash is `tASSOC`.

Comment: If you put something else in place of the class list you get an illuminating error e.g. `rescue 2 => ex` gives "class or module required for rescue clause". You would get the same error with `{ Exception => b }` if `b` were defined, because it's a hash.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise explanation. I once wrote a recursive descent compiler for a language I invented for a 4 bit computer I built in digital design class years ago. It's been a long long time, but the whole grammar discussion is not foreign to me. This helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the syntax breakdown and pointers to how to read it