# How to validate a string whether it contain valid Ruby Symbol literal

Tags: ruby

I have some string inputs, which I want to validate whether it's a valid Ruby Symbol literal. If it is, then convert it to a Symbol. Otherwise return the passed string.

Example,

```
def parse_symbol(str)
  ...          # Validate and convert to Symbol
  # Return Symbol if valid Symbol literal
  # Otherwise return str
end

input1 = ':foo_bar'   #=> Valid Symbol
parse_symbol(input1)  #=> :foo_bar

input2 = ':"foo bar"' #=> Valid Symbol
parse_symbol(input2)  #=> :"foo bar"

input3 = ':foo bar'   #=> Invalid
parse_symbol(input3)  #=> :foo bar

input4 = '::"foo_bar"'   #=> Invalid
parse_symbol(input4)  #=> ::"foo_bar"

...   # all other possible valid and invalid symbol literal goes here
```

> str.to_sym   # Transforms every string into Symbol form

**Edit**

Is `eval` an expensive tool to use here?

> eval(str).is_a?(Symbol) rescue str

Comment: Why does `str` contain a symbol literal? Can't you just pass the string contents and convert it to a symbol using `to_sym`? eg. `str.to_sym` assuming `str` contains `'foo_bar'` and not `':foo_bar'` (although the latter will also work). Or are you meta programming? (Defining helper methods that create methods/classes.)

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Why do you need to translate it to a symbol and why only in certain cases? This sounds like a xy problem to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using a real parser for this.

```
require 'parser/current'
require 'minitest/autorun'

def parse_symbol(str)
  ast = Parser::CurrentRuby.parse(str)
  if ast.type == :sym
    ast.children[0]
  else
    str
  end
rescue Parser::SyntaxError
  str
end

class TestAnswer < Minitest::Test
  def test_1
    assert_equal :foo_bar, parse_symbol(':foo_bar')
  end

  def test_2
    assert_equal :"foo bar", parse_symbol(':"foo bar"')
  end

  def test_3
    assert_equal ":foo bar", parse_symbol(':foo bar')
  end

  def test_4
    assert_equal '::"foo_bar"', parse_symbol('::"foo_bar"')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def parse_symbol(str)
  result = str.scan /^\:(((@@|@|\$)?[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[!\?]?)|(\$([:.><\?!\$\\\/'"@`~\+\;]|\-\w))|(\$[0-9]+)|(<|>|\[\])|"(.*)"|'(.*)')$/
  return str unless !result.empty?

  result[0].drop(1).each do |part|
    return part.to_sym unless part.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with the symbols `:a1` and `:"007"`?

Comment: Haha my bad, it's edited

Comment: or (after your edits) `':"&"'` or `'a!'`?

Comment: See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526761/what-can-a-ruby-symbol-syntax-contain).

Answer (score -1):

Using a regular expression like this.

```rb
def parse_symbol(str)
  if str ~= /:([^:\s]+||"[^:]+")/
    return str.to_sym
  else
    return str
  end
end
```

> Is `eval` an expensive tool to use here?

It might not be that expensive, but it can be dangerous depending on where this input is coming from.

Comment: This answer (at the time I write this comment) has a syntax error (`~=` should be `=~`) and more importantly, does not pass the test of `input2`, whose value is `':"foo bar"'`. The correct output is `:"foo bar"` but this answer produces `:":\"foo bar\""`.

Comment: I have tested this(with corrected syntax `=~`), it converts all input string including `parse_symbol('::foo bar')  #=> :"::foo bar"`. This isn't the expected output.

Comment: This matches `":"`. Why? Because you have `||`, not `|`. Two pipes in a row matches an empty string. Your regex also matches `":007"` even though `:007` is not a valid symbol. Also, what is the point of the capture group? Lastly, you obviously did not test your answer, which is inexcusable. I rarely downvote answers but your answer truly deserves one.